# Lowercase URL's with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, url-rewriting

We're hosting static web pages in an AWS S3 bucket served up by CloudFront. I'm trying to find a solution for user's who may enter a URL with uppercase letters and get a 404. I'm not fluent in JS but here's my first attempt. I think I'm close but not quite there. What am I not understanding?

```
<script>    

    var url = $(location).attr('href');
    url = url.toLowerCase();

    window.history.pushState({ "html": url.html, "pageTitle": url.pageTitle }, "", url);

</script>
```

Comment: Try going to `GOOGLE.COM` or `GoOgLe.CoM`. Capitalization shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MikeC it doesn't matter for hostnames, but paths are generally case-sensitive.  Still...

Answer (score 0):

It really shouldn't matter if accessing uppercase or lowercase, but for your case, you should use:

```
<script>    

    var url = $(location).attr('href');

    window.history.pushState({ "html": url.html.toLowerCase(), "pageTitle": url.pageTitle.toLowerCase() }, "", url);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks flilipebarretto but still a problem: d73711rp9gy8.cloudfront.net/Using-The-library/ Maybe using history is not the way to go?

Comment: Hmm sorry then. I thought your issue was with the capitalization, not how to get the correct url. Try using: document.referrer. Not sure if this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah you were right the first time. My problem is capitalization. http://d73711rp9gy8.cloudfront.net/Using-The-library/ returns a 404 but http://d73711rp9gy8.cloudfront.net/using-the-library/ is where I'm trying to send them to. Wouldn't lowercasing the URL achieve that?